# simplest way to time output of function

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

I am accessing a web API that seems to mysteriously hang every once in a while. Right now I am using print to do some simple logging. I am not familiar with threads or anything like it, and I'm hoping that there's just a simple way to keep a check on how long it's been since a new print statement was returned and gracefully quit my function if a maximum time interval has been reached. Thanks for any input.

Comment: How are you sending these requests? `urllib2` and `requests` both implement a timeout (I know `requests` does for sure).

Comment: I see a 'urllib2.setTimeout(self, t)' method for the FTP protocol handler.

Comment: It's an API-specific library -- nothing as generic as requests. I didn't find a timeout method in it. Good suggestion though; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the time.time() module to get time in seconds; from doc

> 'time() -> floating point number\n\nReturn the current time in seconds
>   since the Epoch.\nFractions of a second may be present if the system
>   clock provides them.'

Use it in code as,

```
import time
tic = time.time() #start
while True:
   do_big_job()
   toc = time.time();
   if ( toc - tic > timeout ):
      break
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused... in this case, do_big_job() would hang, and toc would never be initialized for the break to occur -- I think. What am I missing?

Comment: Multithreading would have to be used to process the time delay.

Comment: So you want to spawn off the task in a new thread, and while you are in the parent do a polling on a flag (shared between master and slave, which slave updates to indicate completion). Clearly when your polling time exceeds timeout you can terminate the slave thread.

Comment: I see there's no easy way out! Thanks.